# Vimeo player doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: html, flash, firefox, vimeo, vimeo-player

I have a problem with the playback of a Vimeo video on Firefox with this configuration:

- LENOVO 40613WG
- Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bits
- Mozilla Firefox 24.0
- Flash Player 11.9.900.117
- No extensions

I'm testing the playback on this page http://player.vimeo.com/api/examples/simple The video doesn't play, exept maybe 1 time on 10.

I have tested on 12 PC they all work. It doesn't work only with this computer.

There is a demo of the problem : http://www.screenr.com/FkYH

Does anyone know a solution for this problem ?

Comment: Try to remove flash completely, and re-install.

Comment: See this link [Vimeo Pro player not working in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/967253) This might sort out your problem.

Comment: When I turn on the safe mode, the Vimeo player works. Then, I tried to desactivate all extensions, but it still doesn't working without the safe mode.

Comment: try and create a new profile with no extensions and no custom theme. http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager

Answer (score 4):

Is your root page HTTPS? We have run into issues with Firefox 24 and Mixed Content.  If your page is HTTPS and the vimeo embed is HTTP then Firefox 24 (by default now) will block the HTTP Content.

FF > About:Config > security.mixed_content.block_active_content > Set to False.

I know we having this issue with screencast but since FF changed it could happen with other video embeds.

Answer (score 0):

Gneisler's response was the right solution for me.  Issue was not the Flash installation, as it worked fine in Chrome.  However FF (running v25) was exhibiting the issue.  Changing the config value as indicated in the response worked.  (Sorry, I did't have enough reputation to comment or promote the answer currently)

I just wanted to add that this could bite you on other sites that make use of Vimeo videos ([example](https://www.temboo.com/videos))